# C++ Compiling windows service with visual studio

Tags: c++, windows, service

hope you could help me. I got a C++ source for my service based on [Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/the-complete-service-sample), still i get linker error compiling it:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
```

as the entry point for windows services is `int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])`

In my case it's `void __cdecl _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[]) { ... }`

There are 1 header and 1 cpp files with a class used by the service and main.cpp contaning entry point and c style service related code. Subsystem is console without any custom entry point set. Still if i add classic `int main(...)` to the code project compiles yet the service does not start from windows service manager returning error.

Please advise how to compile this using `_tmain`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213294/discussion-on-question-by-alex-yi-c-compiling-windows-service-with-visual-stud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, still no luck with `_tmain`. Unfortunately i haven't tried to define `WINAPI WinMain` entry point.

Still if you proceed with `wmain` program entry point and add [code mentioned by Richard Critten](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-entry-point) for a service startup SCManager performs just fine. For a complete service sample refer to [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/the-complete-service-sample).`wmain` will force you to use Unicode yet it shouldn't be such a problem in 2020.

Subsystem should be set as supposed to your needs and no need to set custom entry point.

Thanks to everyone commented.

**UPD** You have to include `tchar.h` in order to use `_tmain`, so all types of entry points will work fine.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah, completely correct solution is including `<tchar.h>`. I've written just in case someone doesn't want it included still preferring to use `_tmain` macro.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you might be suprised but there are still guys alive really caring about what's in the guts of exe they got from a compiler )